# C# LINQ separate objects from others

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with C# that I cannot think of a solution.
basicly I have multiple objects coming in from database and they have attribute of Template type

example( Movie.templateType  where templateTypes are Action, Comedy, Adventure and unspecified)

How can I group them so that unspecified will be separated from other templateTypes

I'm pretty sure it can be done with LINQ groupby statement but i cannot figure it out

Comment: at the core this question has nothing to do with linq - why does a simple foreach loop with an if statement not work for you - what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean it will be "separated"? Do you want to obtain two separate groups of values, or do you just want to ignored the unspecified ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `where` in your query.

```
var movieTemplates = (from mt in yourCollection
                     where mt.TemplateType != "Unspecified"
                     select mt).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to obtain two separate sets (one for specified items and one for specified):

```
var sets = items.GroupBy(i => i.templateType != "unspecified");

// s.Key will be true for the group of specified items and false for the other
var specifiedItems = sets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key);
var unspecifiedItems = sets.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Key);
```

The above is efficient because it only enumerates the original set once, but it is a bit contrived and also requires you to do null checks  on `specifiedItems` and `unspecifiedItems`. A clearer yet slightly less efficient approach that should not require null checks would be:

```
var specifiedItems = items.Where(i => i.templateType != "unspecified");
var unspecifiedItems = items.Where(i => i.templateType == "unspecified");
```